# Multiple Service Calls in ROS2

Tags: ros, ros2, services, nodes

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a sensor library that I am using ROS2 services to make function calls to that library. Is there a way to have multiple services  in one node or do I need to make a new node for each individual service call?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329735/multiple-service-calls-in-ros2/) by [mikepark93](https://answers.ros.org/users/44418/mikepark93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2019-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A node can have any number of `publisher`, `subscription`, `service` or `client`.

```
using std::placeholders::_1;
using std::placeholders::_2;
using std::placeholders::_3;

class MyNode : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
MyNode(std::string name = "my_node") : Node(name)
{
    _service1 = this->create_service<ServiceT1>("service1", std::bind(&MyNode::handle_service_1, this, _1, _2, _3));
    _service2 = this->create_service<ServiceT2>("service2", std::bind(&MyNode::handle_service_2, this, _1, _2, _3));
}

private:
    void handle_service_1(
        const std::shared_ptr<rmw_request_id_t> request_header,
        const std::shared_ptr<ServiceT1::Request> request,
        const std::shared_ptr<ServiceT1::Response> response)
    {
     std::cout<<"This is service 1"<<std::endl;
    }

    void handle_service_2(
        const std::shared_ptr<rmw_request_id_t> request_header,
        const std::shared_ptr<ServiceT2::Request> request,
        const std::shared_ptr<ServiceT2::Response> response);
    {
     std::cout<<"This is service 2"<<std::endl;
    }

    rclcpp::Service<ServiceT1>::SharedPtr _service1;
    rclcpp::Service<ServiceT2>::SharedPtr _service2;
};
```

---

Originally posted by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) with karma: 1322 on 2019-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ShivamPR21](https://answers.ros.org/users/57111/shivampr21/) on 2020-07-29**:
Can we have the same service names for both services and let it be decided by the request type which service to be used for the response.